# How to share a folder and only this folder?

Tags: macos, mac, sharing

I have a Mavericks installed Mac, and want to share a folder called `Data` which placed in  `/Users/Sato/Data` with another windows 7 PC.

So I followed a post to setup shared folder, and it works. But I have one problem.

Not only the folder I want to share is being shared, but also my `$HOME` folder, `/Users` and `/` are all being shared.

Comment: You followed **a post**, that makes no sense. Please add the source and we can at least see the steps you've done.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up what folders are shared by:

- open System Preferences
- click on Sharing

[image: sharing]

using the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> you can add or remove folders to be shared.